# BeautifulSoup choosing a line from output

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I try to make a python script that gets the dam occupancy rates from a website. Here is the code:

```
baraj_link = "https://www.turkiye.gov.tr/istanbul-su-ve-kanalizasyon-idaresi-baraj-doluluk-oranlari"
response = requests.get(baraj_link)
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, "lxml")

values_list = []
values = soup.find_all('dl',{re.compile('compact')})
for val in values:
    text = val.find_next('dt').text
    value = val.text
    values_list.append((text,value))
baraj = values_list[0][1]
```

The output is like this:

```
Tarih
18/01/2021
Genel Doluluk Oranı (%)
29,48
```

Genel Doluluk Oranı means occupancy rate. I need the value of occupancy rate which writes in next line like 29,48. How can I get this value from output?

Comment: You need to make the question self-contained -- for example by including some sample HTML in the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cause question and expected result is not that clearly as mentioned I just point to the output of occupancy rate.

**Get the value by `split()` the string**

Prerequisite is that the value is always the last `substring` in `string`.

```
value = val.text.split()[-1]
```

Answer (score 0):

from you output `baraj` split it with `'\n'` like `baraj.split('\n')[-2]` then use index `[-2]`